# How to find package for installed file in Brew?

Tags: bash, homebrew

How can I identify the package/formula for a given file, or a listing of all of a package's owned files, in Homebrew?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

To see all files in a package:

```
brew ls <package>
```

To find the package for a file, look at the file like this:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/whatever
```

If it was installed by Homebrew, it will be a symlink into `/usr/local/Cellar/something`, so that will tell you what package it's from.

Comment: `brew ls <package>` doesn't work unless `<package>` has already been installed.

Comment: That's exactly how it should work. If it hasn't been installed, the ~path~ can't exist

Answer (score 11):

Just wrote this dirty function to get you the brew package name a file belongs to:

```
function brew_find_pkg {
    file_to_search="$@"

    for package in $(brew list); do
        brew ls $package | grep -E -q "/${file_to_search}$"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo $package
            break
        fi
    done
}
```

Just type that in the terminal. And then to find to find the brew package a file belongs to, say the file `gsed`, just call the function like this

```
brew_find_pkg gsed
```

Note that the function will not work if you provide the full path of the file.

Comment: If you have a lot of brew formulas installed, this can be quite slow.

Comment: @Aphoid True. Since it has to inspect the files of every brew package one by one.

Answer (score 6):

The package name can be determined based on the symbolic link which points to the binary (`Cellar/PACKAGE/...`), e.g.

```
$ ls -la $(which awk) # => gawk
lrwxr-xr-x 1 kenorb 28 May 20  2015 /usr/local/bin/awk -> ../Cellar/gawk/4.1.1/bin/awk

$ ls -la $(which seq) # => coreutils
lrwxr-xr-x 1 kenorb 14 Apr  8  2015 /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/seq -> ../../bin/gseq
```

Answer (score 2):

This function works for commands stored in the `$( brew --prefix )/bin` directory.

```
function brew_find_pkg {

    cmds_to_search="$@"
    brew_bin=$( brew --prefix )/bin

    for cmd in $cmd_to_search ; do

        if [ -L $brew_bin/$cmd ] ; then
            \ls -l $brew_bin/$cmd |cut -f 2 -d '>'
        else
            echo "$cmd is not a brew command"
        fi
    done
}
```

E.g.:

```
$ brew_find_pkg gawk gcc alskdfja
 ../Cellar/gawk/4.1.4_1/bin/gawk
 ../Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/bin/gcc
alskdfja is not a brew command
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made a Homebrew tap for it.

Install

```
% brew tap ten0s/brew-cache
```

Build/update cache

```
% brew cache -u
Building cache: fcbb2f2ca6958fa9218c035e8cfef96cd6e92164
Cache: fcbb2f2ca6958fa9218c035e8cfef96cd6e92164 is built
```

Search

```
% brew cache -s 'lib/libgtk-3.dylib'
gtk+3 3.24.35
```

See https://github.com/ten0s/homebrew-brew-cache for more detail`

Comment: I've amended a couple of things: https://github.com/moreaki/homebrew-brew-cache. Unfortunately, neither `brew ls $pkg` nor `brew list --verbose $pkg` actually show all the correct file entries on ARM-based (M1 and M2) macOS nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Find and brew prefix, (e.g. for opencv):

```
find `brew --prefix opencv3`/ -exec ls -l {} \;
```

(Please note judicious use of -exec, and never forget those **\;**'s, folks .. its how find knows that the -exec arg-list is finished..)

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew packages are installed to $(brew --prefix)/Cellar (normally /usr/local/Cellar).

To find out which packages a file belongs to, one simple approach is:

```
$ find $(brew --prefix)/Cellar/ | grep somefilename
```

Comment: More accurately, `find $(brew --cellar) -name somefilename`

Answer (score 0):

Although trawling the filesystem is something that I often do, it's definitely not needed in the common case here if the mystery file is a program. Generally the package a given program in provided by is linked into the cellar whose path shows the package, so just run something like this example:

```
$ ll $(which benchmark_xl)          
lrwxr-xr-x  1 slu  admin    42B Oct  9 14:07 /opt/homebrew/bin/benchmark_xl -> ../Cellar/jpeg-xl/0.8.2_1/bin/benchmark_xl
```

This easily explains that the mystery `benchmark_xl` binary I found belongs to the jpeg-xl library. Other tools would be used to figure out what other packages depend on this library to explain why it is installed on the system.