# Where can I find python in mac when I installed it with brew?

Tags: python, macos

I installed python with brew, but I didn't removed the bundled python in OSX. Where can I find the binary? Does brew installs it automatically in /usr/local/bin ?

Comment: Maybe helpful [How to find package for installed file in Brew?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915683/how-to-find-package-for-installed-file-in-brew)

Comment: Thanks! It helped me!

Comment: While not answering this question directly, there are plenty of pointers in https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md where it gets installed.

Comment: if you want to find any executable in path, use the which command. IE type **which python** . It can be a symbolic link though. In that case use ls -l executable to find real path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to find the binary under /usr/local/bin.